# col-sm-* width issue inside absolute div on Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, absolute

I'm triying to make sidebar megamenu.

But i stacked megamenu width because of all widths percentage.
When i use px width, its working. I dont want to use as pixels.

Tried here: http://jsfiddle.net/p8SeB/

When you hover mouse on `Clothing & Accessories`, you will see the issue

#### HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="sidemenu yamm list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Deal of the Day <b class="right-caret"></b>
                            </a>

                <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action 2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Clothing & Accessories <b class="right-caret"></b>
                            </a>

                <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="yamm-content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="list-group">    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                                                      Cras justo odio
                                                    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="embed-container">
                                        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/5606758" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                        <h5><span class="light">Awesome</span> Video</h5>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, maiores.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Electronic <b class="right-caret"></b>
                            </a>

                <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Another 4</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Home, Dolls, Toys <b class="right-caret"></b>
                            </a>

                <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Another 5</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Collection & Art <b class="right-caret"></b>
                            </a>

                <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Another 6</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Personal Care & Fitness <b class="right-caret"></b>
                            </a>

                <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Another 7</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Music, Movies, Books, Games <b class="right-caret"></b>
                            </a>

                <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Another 8</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Cars, Motorcycles Accessories <b class="right-caret"></b>
                            </a>

                <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Another 9</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/790x300" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/790x300" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/790x300" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.sidemenu { position: relative }
.sidemenu > .list-group-item { cursor: pointer; padding: 0; position: initial;}
.sidemenu > .list-group-item > a { width: 100%; padding: 10px 15px; display: block; color: #333; text-decoration: none; position: relative; }

.sidemenu-sub 
{
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    top: -2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100% !important;
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    z-index: 1001;
    border-left: 0;

    webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.sidemenu > .list-group-item:hover 
{
    border-right: 0;    
}

.sidemenu > .list-group-item:hover  .dropdown-menu
{
    display: block;
}

.sidemenu > li.list-group-item:hover, li.list-group-item:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.right-caret 
{
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;

    bottom:40%;
    top: 40%;
    right: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use percentages that are lower than 100% for this one as you're enclosing within divs that are smaller than what you need in that specific submenu. You could try to widen the `ul` to 250% within 'Clothing & Accessories':

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Clothing & Accessories <b class="right-caret"></b>
</a>
    <ul class="sidemenu-sub dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:250%">
    <!--                         this is what I added |_________________|
    ... -->

    </ul>
</li>
```

**[I updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8SeB/1/)**

Comment: I would to make dynamic width. %250 width well for only current `li` node. But that width so wide for some nodes, so narrow for another nodes. I have to set auto width for all.

Comment: When i set width as px or percent like yours, its working. But this is not dynamic method. Some `li` nodes narrow, some `li` nodes wide. %250 width well for wider but not compatible for narrow menu. So when you set width `250%` `Deal of the Day` menu items, you will see that so wide.

Comment: it's dynamic enough for me, still don't get what you want... you want all the submenu backgrounds to have the same width all the time? or do you want the embedded video to be placed underneath the submenus...? what is it that you want the end-result to look like?

Comment: All submenus width must be different. Some submenus have 2 cols, other ones have 3 cols. When i set width 250%, it's so wide for single col.

Comment: if you set it to 250% for that one `ul` element only, it will only be that wide for that one menu item nicely covering the background of the video... of course if you apply it to all, it will make all of them wider, so don't do it.